# How to float:left a container with an image having a relative width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align to the left an image with a width which is relative to the page width. There are couple of unfortunate constraints which I cannot change:

- the image has a wrapper,
- I **cannot apply width to the wrapper** because class responsible for the width is applied to the image (and I cannot change that too :D),
- the solution must be CSS-only.

The structure looks like this:

```
<p>Lipsum...</p>

<div class="align-left">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/" class="width50" alt="lipsum" width="1000" height="1000">
</div>

<p>Lipsum...</p>
```

CSS:

```
.align-left {
    float: left;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
}

.width50 {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```

**See**: http://jsfiddle.net/xnt27crz/2/

**Question:** Is it possible to style the `div.align-left` in a way that it does not take 100% width? Its width should equal the width of an image + its own padding.

More facts:

- The closest I got was to float the image, not the div (so it is 0px high), but it was awful and caused other issues.
- I think that this can be achieved with flexbox, but I'm looking for IE9+ support.
- I'm looking for a "safe" solution because it will be then used by many developers in many scenarios that I cannot predict.
- **Edit**: The real case is much more complicated, hence the constraints. You can see the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/n1kayb2o/3/. Note that the structure inside the editor is different than the input HTML. There's additional wrapper which glues together the figure and the drag handle that it has and some other elements that may be needed (e.g. an overlay).

Comment: [Something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/xnt27crz/3/)

Comment: Nope - as I mentioned in the question - the width cannot be applied to the wrapper.

Comment: @Reinmar your best shot would be here http://csscreator.com/ ... incase you don't get answered on SO . I have run into alot of complex problems and got it solved there . stackoverflow and csscreator are always my last resorts  , though the latter rates slightly higher !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tough problem. I had to read the spec to help you out and here is my result.

**It's impossible** to solve the problem with the given constraints since it all depends on the width of the image (also called "replaced element")

Why?

Let's read the spec http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#float-width

> If 'margin-left', or 'margin-right' are computed as 'auto', their used value is '0'.
>
> If 'width' is computed as 'auto', **the used value is the "shrink-to-fit" width.**
>
> Calculation of the shrink-to-fit width is similar to calculating the width of a table cell using the automatic table layout algorithm. Roughly: calculate the preferred width by formatting the content without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur, and also calculate the preferred minimum width, e.g., by trying all possible line breaks. CSS 2.1 does not define the exact algorithm. Thirdly, find the available width: in this case, this is the width of the containing block minus the used values of 'margin-left', 'border-left-width', 'padding-left', 'padding-right', 'border-right-width', 'margin-right', and the widths of any relevant scroll bars.
>
> **Then the shrink-to-fit width is: min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width)**.

Lets do the "math" for your case

```
Preferred minimum width = 1000px (real width of the image)
Available width = assume 1990 (roughly page width)
Preferred width = 1000px (real width of the image)

min(max(1000, 1990), 1000) = 1000
```

As a proof http://jsfiddle.net/xnt27crz/5/ with 200px image

**Summary**

In your case the floated div will get the width equal to the real width of the image.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this for me. I noticed this behaviour when I was building a sample for the question, but it's good to confirm it with the spec. It means that we will need to change the engine to move all classes so the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you can just add all the styles to the image itself.

```
.align-left .width50 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: red;
}
```

```css
.align-left .width50 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>

<div class="align-left">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/" alt="lipsum" width="1000" height="1000" class="width50">
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
```

***Edit:*** this doesn't solve issue (after OP clarified the question) as the parent div still collapses. But I'll keep it here, someone might be interested in it in the future.

Comment: just not sure if OP wants  wrapper of img with bg red or not.

Comment: That makes the div invisible (it has 0 height). As I wrote at the end of the question - this is not something that I can accept. I striped some details from the question to keep it simple, but the real structure is more complex. So I really want to have the `div`  wrapping the image.

Comment: I'll try to provide a more realistic structure, but it may take me some time.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not looking to fix this single scenario, but the whole engine which is very generic. I can change CKEditor (namely - I can move the width class to the wrapper), but it will mean a backwards incompatible change. Before we'll decide to make it, I want to make sure that there is no other solution.

Comment: @Reinmar how about applying a clearfix on the parent of the img ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik: What do you mean? I know what clearfix does, but I don't understand how it could help me :).

Comment: @Reinmar , i assume thats now what u want , but if u go with sdcr's solution you could have a clearfix on the parent so that it does't collapse !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik It doesn't seem to work, see the demo - http://jsfiddle.net/w56xsg1z/ the float won't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do the width 50% to your align-left div, and then do a 100% on the image? Now the div would be 50% of the page, and left floated, while the image is 100% inside this div?

I really don't know if this is the solution or not because it seems too simple..
And maybe I've misunderstood your answer.

Anyway,
Greetings and good luck!

Comment: One of the constraints is that the width cannot be applied to the container, because class responsible for it is applied to the image. But as @wookieb proved, there will be no other solution than moving all classes to the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Is it possible to style the div.align-left in a way that it does not take 100% width? Its width should equal the width of an image + its own padding.

This is an example https://jsfiddle.net/n1kayb2o/5/

But if you want it more responsive, that max-width of the container (`figure`) will not exceed it's container - then it could be much more complicated. Especially if you want your class `image30` to have for example `30%` of it's container even if image inside it is more wider.

Comment: Your solution indeed answers my question, but that question only :D The topic is "How to float:left a container with an image having a relative width".