# How do I hide the overflow of an image if it's too big for the parent container?

Tags: css, image, overflow

How can I hide the overflow of this image without removing it from the flow? If I made it a background image or positioned it absolutely, the text would flow right through it, and I don't want that. Applying overflow:hidden to the parent only expands the height of it to contain the whole image. What I want is:

- The image to float right
- The text to wrap around the image
- The height of the section to be determined by the height of the text only
- The image to be cropped if necessary

https://jsfiddle.net/krishunt/e7mzo54c/

```
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: helvetica;
            color: #333333;
        }

        section {
            background-color: #E3E2DE;
            padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
            max-width: 1200px;
        }

        .pull-right {
            float: right;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <img class="pull-right" src="http://thomasprintworks.com/temp/copier.png" />
        <h2>Title of Section</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla dapibus. Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit lobortis. Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id.</p>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: I think the main problem here is that you are trying to ignore the image element, yet wrap around it at the same time. That's assuming I have understood your question correctly. Could you perchance provide an illustration of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Like this: http://thomasprintworks.com/temp/crop.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the `<section>`, this should work!

Comment: It doesn't. overflow:hidden alone just clears the float. Overflow:hidden plus a static height crops the image, but the height of the parent container needs to be unrestricted because it's a fluid width site.

Comment: Check my [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/yihamo/4/edit?html,css), with your code it works by just putting `overflow:hidden` to `section`. There are some problems with floats, which browser are you using?

Comment: Also sometimes this becomes impossible without knowing the height of the container, refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704019/how-to-floatleft-a-container-with-an-image-having-a-relative-width)

Comment: I looked at your JSBin; in Mac Safari and Chrome, the image is not being cropped; the float is just cleared creating a huge gap under the text. I'm beginning to believe what I want to do is impossible.